# Kubernetes Fake Client doesn't handle GenerateName in ObjectMeta

Tags: unit-testing, go, kubernetes, client-go

When using the Kubernetes [Fake Client](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes/fake) to write unit tests, I noticed that it fails to create two identical objects which have their [`ObjectMeta.GenerateName`](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1#ObjectMeta) field set to some string. A real cluster accepts this specification and generates a unique name for each object.

Running the following test code:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    corev1 "k8s.io/api/core/v1"
    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes/fake"
)

func TestFake(t *testing.T) {
    ctx := context.Background()
    client := fake.NewSimpleClientset()

    _, err := client.CoreV1().Secrets("default").Create(ctx, &corev1.Secret{
        ObjectMeta: metav1.ObjectMeta{
            GenerateName: "generated",
        },
        StringData: map[string]string{"foo": "bar"},
    }, metav1.CreateOptions{})
    assert.NoError(t, err)

    _, err = client.CoreV1().Secrets("default").Create(ctx, &corev1.Secret{
        ObjectMeta: metav1.ObjectMeta{
            GenerateName: "generated",
        },
        StringData: map[string]string{"foo": "bar"},
    }, metav1.CreateOptions{})
    assert.NoError(t, err)
}
```

fails with

```
--- FAIL: TestFake (0.00s)
    /Users/mihaitodor/Projects/kubernetes/main_test.go:44: 
            Error Trace:    main_test.go:44
            Error:          Received unexpected error:
                            secrets "" already exists
            Test:           TestFake
FAIL
FAIL    kubernetes  0.401s
FAIL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/issues/439#issuecomment-403867107) GitHub issue comment:

> the fake clientset doesn't attempt to duplicate server-side behavior
> like validation, name generation, uid assignment, etc. if you want to
> test things like that, you can add reactors to mock that behavior.

To add the required reactor, we can insert the following code before creating the `corev1.Secret` objects:

```
client.PrependReactor(
    "create", "*",
    func(action k8sTesting.Action) (handled bool, ret runtime.Object, err error) {
        ret = action.(k8sTesting.CreateAction).GetObject()
        meta, ok := ret.(metav1.Object)
        if !ok {
            return
        }

        if meta.GetName() == "" && meta.GetGenerateName() != "" {
            meta.SetName(names.SimpleNameGenerator.GenerateName(meta.GetGenerateName()))
        }

        return
    },
)
```

There are a few gotchas in there:

- The `Clientset` contains an embedded [`Fake`](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/client-go/testing#Fake) structure which has the [`PrependReactor`](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/client-go/testing#Fake.PrependReactor) method we need to call for this use case (there are a few others). This code [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/d6c83109f030902f150f03f252311d2749cb6094/testing/fake.go#L140-L145) is invoked when creating such objects.
- The `PrependReactor` method has 3 parameters: `verb`, `resource` and `reaction`. For `verb`, `resource`, I couldn't find any named constants, so, in this case, "create" and "secrets" (strange that it's not "secret") seem to be the correct values for them if we want to be super-specific, but setting `resource` to "*" should be acceptable in this case.
- The `reaction` parameter is of type [ReactionFunc](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/client-go/testing#ReactionFunc), which takes an [`Action`](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/client-go/testing#Action) as a parameter and returns `handled`, `ret` and `err`. After some digging, I noticed that the `action` parameter will be cast to [`CreateAction`](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/client-go/testing#CreateAction), which has the `GetObject()` method that returns a `runtime.Object` instance, which can be cast to [`metav1.Object`](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1#Object). This interface allows us to get and set the various metadata fields of the underlying object. After setting the object `Name` field as needed, we have to return `handled = false`, `ret = mutatedObject` and `err = nil` to instruct the calling code to execute the remaining reactors.
- Digging through the `apiserver` code, I noticed that the `ObjectMeta.Name` field [is generated](https://github.com/kubernetes/apiserver/blob/f0b4663d4cd5caceddb64fd239053d29208104cd/pkg/registry/rest/create.go#L112-L114) from the `ObjectMeta.GenerateName` field using the [`names.SimpleNameGenerator.GenerateName`](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/storage/names) utility.